# Example for a UML-Project of a plugin-based software.

Tags: c++, plugins, uml

We are going to develop a strong plugin-based c++ software. There is only few source-code examples for it. Due to the big size of the project, we want to do a simple software modeling, before we start to implement it. First of all class and sequence diagramms. We are newbies to UML, due to this reason, it would be nice, to have an UML-Example for a plugin-based project. We haven't found any examples for it on the web. Design patterns we want to use are i.e. plugins, plugins manager, factory method, singleton and some others. And now my question:

Do you know a (simple) example for a UML-Project for a similar software design?

Thank you.

Cheers Alex.

Comment: I am afraid the question is not totally up to the rules of the site, for there can be different answers to it, but I personally like the theme, so, +1 and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, that's off-topic. Lucky you slipped through the closing process, For the future please  read the help on how to ask on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the examples of this kind, but I can suggest you a set of diagrams/views that you should probably create in this kind of project. UML is very flexible tool and software projects are so diverse in nature, that it is hard to set up rules. You should listen to your developer instinct and simply model what you need in order to go forward with the project.

So...

1- **Components (mandatory)**
As this is a plug-in project, there are implicite external dependencies involved. You should make a component diagram to show your future plug-in (a component) as a black-box in its environment. Another obvious component will be the base-tool (to which your komponent will be plugged-in)
- Model all relevant interfaces between parts! This is fundamental
- Use stereotypes to show the implementation platform for each component (e.g. C++)

2- **Use Cases (optional)**
Here you can identify your Users (Actors) and what they can do with the plug-in (use cases). An alternative would be to capture reqs using wireframe model (non UML) or something like that.

3- **Conceptual views (optional)**
You did not tell anything about your plug-in functional logic. How complex is it? If the plug-in logic is very complex and has many concepts, algorithm, etc. then you should consider modelling this aspect on the conceptual level. Problem concepts and their relationships are captured using class diagrams. In addition you can use state machines (for active classes), activity diagrams (for complex algorithms), sequences (relevant scenarios), etc. all on conceptual analysis level (no implementation details)
If your plug-in domain logic is trivial, you can minimize this view. Sometimes a single state machine helps or an activity diagram, etc.

4- **Architecture (mandatory)**
Here you can use components and/or class diagrams to show the high-level view of your plug-in internal structure. This view extens the black-box view (explained in 1-), giving a white box complement. Only main modules are shown with an accent on interfaces between them and especially towards the external world.

5- **Design (optional)**
Here you should be pragmatic and not do this view just to have it done. If the plug-in is not very large and you have a trained team, the Architecture view will do the job. All depending on your plug-in complexity you can decide to show one or more levels of hierarchically related view. Components are typically on the top level, including more components and/or design classes.
Note that we speak the implementation-language on this level and ALL elements should have a clear stereotype (C++, DLL, EXE, etc).
Design view should also have some behavior diagrams of choice (sequences, activities, states, etc), again on the implementation level.

**Traceability**
The last but not the least. All these views look at the same underlaying system from different points of view and in different stages. Therefore there are a lot of implicit or explicit dependencies and relationships between the elements in different view. You should be fully aware of them and even show some of them on separate diagrams or via traceability matrix (some tools support it). Some traces you can make between proposed views:

- 1->4 Black-box and the corresponding white-boxes
- 4->5 high-level to low-level map (a component on architecture level is implemented by classes on the design level)
- 2->4, 2->5 Which components/classes will participate in which use cases
- 2->3 a single use case logic can be further specified through some conceptual modelling
- behavior diagrams are strongly related to structural elements (state machines belong to classes or components), sequence diagram includes collaborating instances of classes/components, activities can show lverall usage scenarios of components or a class's method algorithm, etc.
  etc.

There are a lot of ways to do this work and nobody can give you a concrete winning formula. UML modelling should assist you in your analysis/design work, beign a natural side-product of it. If you feel that you don't know what to model or you don't see the clear purpose of a diagram - just don't do it.

Comment: Excuse me, but according to your p.3, algorithms can be modeled by class diagrams. You should better rephrase the appropriate sentences.

Comment: @Gangnus: Thanks, I've just done it. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Much better now :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

- As for "factory method, singleton and some others", expressed in class diagrams, read the [Gang of Four book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612).
- As for plugins, you are looking in bad places. They are to be expressed in means of component and package diagrams, not class ones.
- As for sequence diagrams, (also state machines, timing, activity...) , they are not intended for showing the problems of structure. And plugin is a structural term. Behavioral diagrams are useful, but they don't have any specifics when used for plugins.
- For interactions of plugins, also look for UML communication and interactions overview diagrams. And maybe look at diagrams in the book ["Enterprise Integration Patterns..."](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683). Their diagrams are not UML standard ones, but IMHO, are very convenient and useful for modelling of interactions on the level of components and packages (or plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my small link collection for the plugin architecture topic:

1. [C++ basic implementation](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/plugin-architecture/)
2. [Dobbs article series for that topic with all the implementation details, c++](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/building-your-own-plugin-framework-part/204202899)
3. [Microsoft article, using .net features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx)
4. [Implementation details considering loading dlls in c++](http://3dgep.com/?p=1759)